# Referencing to a changing function in a loop

Tags: vba, function, loops

In code below I would like to reference to a function in a loop. Name of the function should change from InputDateRange to InputDateRange1..2..3.. 
Unfortunately I'm getting value of variable C as a string in quotes("InputDateRange1"). How can I get C as InputDateRange1 - without quotes?
Thanks in advance for your reply
DP

```
For j = 1 To 3
C = "InputDateRange" & j
With DataSet
     .Close
     .Source = C
     .Open
End With
Range("G4").CopyFromRecordset DataSet
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.Run`.

Say the following was in module 1 of this workbook. Note I am not using the return values deliberately.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long, C As String

    For i = 1 To 2
        C = "Msg" + CStr(i)
        Application.Run "Module1." & C
    Next
End Sub

Public Function Msg1() As Long
    MsgBox "I am msg 1"
    Msg1 = 1
End Function

Public Function Msg2() As Long
    MsgBox "I am msg 2"
    Msg2 = 2
End Function
```